# Is it possible to use Style System's breakpoints inside a Styled-Component?

Tags: css, reactjs, media-queries, styled-components, rebass

I would like to use styled-system's breakpoint and sizing mechanism inside a styled component.

Currently, I have to use 'react-media', which solves my problem, but this solution comes with a big amount of code duplication. Here is my current solution to set a StyledComponent's border-radius based on the screen size:

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import theme from '../../theme'
import Media from 'react-media'

const StyledImg = styled.img`
  border-radius: ${props => (props.size / 4)};
`

function ProfileImage (props) {
  const breakpoint = theme.breakpoints[0]

  return <Media query={`(min-width: ${breakpoint})`}>
      {matches =>
        matches ? (
        <StyledImg size={props.size[1]} src={props.src} />
      ) : (
        <StyledImg size={props.size[0]} src={props.src} />
      )
    }
  </Media>
}

function ProfileCard (props) {
  return <Box bg='grey' width={1}>
    <ProfileImage width={[10, 20]} src={props.src}>
  </Box>
}

export default ProfileImage
```

Is it possible to get the current breakpoint index? 
Can I write something like this:

```
const StyledImg = styled.img`
  border-radius: ${props => (props.size[theme.currentBreakpointIndex] / 4)};
`

function ProfileImage (props) {
  return <StyledImg {...props} />
}

function ProfileCard (props) {
  return <Box bg='grey' width={1}>
    <ProfileImage size={[10, 20]} src={props.src}>
  </Box>
}

export default ProfileImage
```

Comment: This post may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50009139/with-styled-components-how-to-only-apply-a-style-to-small-devices?rq=1

Comment: Thanks Bonnie, it isn't what I'm looking for, but it can solve the problem.

Comment: If you (really) want to do that, you need to keep track of the browser width yourself. For example a hook in your App component that updates a global state ( like redux ) and get that data when you need it ( in case of redux, connect ).

I actually think you don't need that, also border-radius can be adjusted with media-queries

Answer (score 0):

Reading [this](https://styled-system.com/theme-specification/#media-queries) they suggest you inject breakpoints into queries and put them in the theme. You cant then access them like this:

```
styled.div`
   ${({theme: {mediaQueries: {small}}}) => small} {
       color: red;
   }
`
```

This solution uses css to change styles however (but in my opinion that's how it should be done).